# CodeIgniter - Optional parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm building my first CodeIgniter application and I need to make URLs like follows:

```
controllername/{uf}/{city}
```

Example: /rj/rio-de-janeiro
This example should give me 2 parameters: $uf ('rj') and $city ('rio-de-janeiro')

Another URL possible is:

```
controllername/{uf}/{page}
```

Example: /rj/3
This example should give me 2 parameters: $uf ('rj') and $page (3)

In other words, the parameters "city" and "page" are optionals.
I can't pass something like '/uf/city/page'. I need always or 'city' OR 'page'.
But I don't know how to configure these routes in CodeIgniter configuration to point to same method (or even to different methods).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've found the correct result:

```
$route['controllername/(:any)/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'ddd/index/$1/$2/$3';
$route['controllername/(:any)/(:num)'] = 'ddd/index/$1/null/$2'; // try 'null' or '0' (zero)
$route['controllername/(:any)'] = 'ddd/index/$1';
```

The Index method (inside "ControllerName") should be:

```
public function Index($uf = '', $slug = '', $pag = 0)
{
    // some code...

    if (intval($pag) > 0)
    {
        // pagination
    }

    if (!empty($slug))
    {
        // slug manipulation
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone.
Thank you all.

Comment: It still doesn't pass the 'null' in my case. I always get the next parameter on this place.

Comment: @V.Vachev try to pass 0 (zero) instead null.

Comment: That's exactly how I did it, and it works correctly. Null seems to be some 'special/reserved' word for the routes. It definitely has different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function my_test_function($not_optional_param, $optional_param = NULL)
  { 
   //do your stuff here
  }
```

have you tried this?

Comment: Yes. But the second parameter is variant. Sometimes is a string (city slug), other times is a number (page).

Comment: Great! I can also use Regular Expressions instead of ":any" and ":num". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For example, let’s say you have a URI like this:

1. example.com/index.php/mycontroller/myfunction/hello/world
2. example.com/index.php/mycontroller/myfunction/hello

Your method will be passed URI segments 3 and 4 (“hello” and “world”):

class MyController extends CI_Controller {

```
public function myFunction($notOptional, $optional = NULL)
{
    echo $notOptional; // will return 'hello'.
    echo $optional; // will return 'world' using the 1st URI and 'NULL' using the 2nd.
}
```

}

Reference: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html